# Div Scrollbar - Any way to style it?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, scrollbar

Is there anyway to control the styling of the scrollbars of a div tag?  I am experiencing some contrast issues between IE7 and FireFox 3.5.2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using javascript you can style the scroll bars. Which works fine in IE as well as FF.

Check the below links

[From Twinhelix](http://www.twinhelix.com/dhtml/divscroll/)
, 
[Example 2](http://www.solutoire.com/experiments/scrollbar/index.html)
, 
[Example 3](http://www.n-son.com/scripts/jsScrolling/example2.html)
[or] you can find some 30 type of scroll style types by click the below link
[30 scrolling techniques](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't in Firefox, Safari, etc. You can in Internet Explorer. There are several scripts out there that will allow you to make a scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

[This one does well its scrolling job](http://www.n-son.com/scripts/jsScrolling/jsScroller.html). It's very easy to understand, just really few lines of code, well written and totally readable.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the web I find some simple way to style scrollbars.

This is THE guy!
http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task

And here my implementation!
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1471066/cloudBI/cssScrollbars.png

```
/* Turn on a 13x13 scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 13px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

/* Turn on single button up on top, and down on bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    display: block;
}

/* Turn off the down area up on top, and up area on bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement {
    display: none;
}

/* Place The scroll down button at the bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    display: none;
}

/* Place The scroll up button at the up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    display: none;
}

/* Place The scroll down button at the bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
    display: none;
}

/* Place The scroll up button at the up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px dashed pink;
}

/* Top area above thumb and below up button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start {
    border: 0px;
}

/* Bottom area below thumb and down button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end {
    border: 0px;
}

/* Track below and above */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: silver;
}

/* The thumb itself */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}

/* The thumb itself */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}

/* Corner */
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner:vertical {
    background-color: black;
}

/* Resizer */
::-webkit-scrollbar-resizer:vertical {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also the iScroll project which allows you to style the scrollbars plus get it to work with touch devices.  http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4